# Does every user of a Twitter app need their own Consumer key?

Tags: twitter-oauth

I made an application for Twitter, and it works. Now my friends want to use it as well. I placed the program at http://example.com/twitter/mytwitter.php.

Can everybody share the same consumer key or must each one fill out the Twitter request form, pointing to mytwitter.php and get his own consumer key?

Answer (score 0):

A Twitter application has a single Consumer key/secret and Callback URL.  If your app changes domains (which may happen if someone else uses your code for their app) then the Callback URL specified in your Twitter app settings (tied to your Consumer key/secret) will be wrong.

Each unique domain that the app is running on needs its own Twitter app profile with its own Consumer key/secret and Callback URL.